# CSS mobile - text won't resize

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, font-size

I'm trying to add a mobile version to a simple website but I cannot seem to get any of the text to resize upon changing the window size. To take a single example on the page I'm trying to get the text in #bannerText to resize and the letter spacing to spread out. #bannerText's only parents are body > page > banner. Here are the important snippets of the code:

```
body{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
font-size:16px;
}

.page { 
   position: relative;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

.banner a{
font-weight:bolder;
font-family: sans-serif, Verdana, Geneva;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.banner p{
 margin:0px; 
 }


/* ----Mobile only---- */

@media screen and (max-width:480px){

 body{
   background-image: url("images/mwater.jpg");
   background-size:100%;
 }

 .banner{
   margin: 2%;
   padding-top: 4%;
   opacity: 0.7;
 }    

 #bannerText{
   font-size:0.8em;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 0.4em;
   margin-bottom:10%;
  }
```

Things I have tried include:

Ensuring I have the correct  tag in the

Changing font-size to a % in body and bannerText

After many attempts and searches I really can't see where I'm going wrong.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Can you create fiddle ?

Comment: With the CSS and implied HTML, it appears to work as you want it: https://jsfiddle.net/cuw5ynfa/

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-size:0.8em !important;`